# Laravel how to call dispatch job on string class name

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to call a dispatch job using class from string ?
I try to run the function like this `app()->make($jobClass)::dispatch($agentId)->onQueue("default");` .
And I also try this `app($jobClass)::dispatch($agentId)->onQueue("default");` .

Nothing is working, I got error :

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ 
>   $agentSearchId ]] in class App\Jobs\AgentSearchJob

. `$jobClass` is a string class name like this `App\Jobs\AgentSearchJob`. I usually call a string class with 
`app()` helper, it ussualy work. But not in this case.

Comment: it seems `App\Jobs\AgentSearchJob` constructor requires `$agentSearchId` param value but service container cannot provide this value for the constructor. you had better to configure your service on `App\ServiceProvider::register()`

Comment: if I'm call like this `AgentSearchJob::dispatch($agentId)->onQueue("default");` , it's working normally. But the class name are on database, so the only way to call it are using using app() helper. Or is there any other way maybe ?

Comment: have you tried `(new $jobClass)->dispatch($agentId)->onQueue("default")` ?

Comment: yes, it does. In you case you dont need laravel for this task, just: `$className = Foo::class; call_user_func_array([new $className, 'myMethod'], ['myParam']);`

Comment: @NMahurin I tried that, same error.

Comment: @felipsmartins ok gonna try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to resolve it. The following should just work:

```
$jobClass::dispatch($agentId)->onQueue("default");
```

Comment: I never ever thought about using the variable directly. This is the simple answer. Thanks a lot man.