# Laravel - Dispatch job by string class name

Tags: laravel, cron, queue, jobs

I have a job table, i am store class name in "job" field. I am trying call and run job class from database table.

This example works.

```
    $class = \App\Models\BulkJobs::with('action')->first();
    app($class->action->job)->dispatch();
```

When I call without a construct the job goes into the queue. When i pass a parameter job dispatch function, job give me a error.

Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $property]] in class App\Jobs\Bulk\SetCategoriesToCartJob

```
    app($class->action->job)->dispatch('some property');
    //OR
    app($class->action->job)::dispatch('some property');
    $class->action->job->dispatch('some property');
    $class->action->job::dispatch('some property');
```

I would be glad if you have advice for the solution.

I have a job table, i have a jobs table. i am store class name in "job" field. When I call without a construct the job goes into the queue. When i pass a parameter job dispatch function, job give me a error.

Comment: if you have a required parameter in a constructor how is the container supposed to know what to pass to it for you? check the documentation for the service container and how to 'resolve' things from it

Comment: Thank you for answer, someone stated that such an example works in the below link. I thought there might be a detail I missed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596793/14856989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem. I init my class name a variable before. When i call variable statically work for me.

```
$job = $cartBulkAction->action->job;
$job::dispatch($cartBulkAction->id);
```